# Symfony cache default folder path

Tags: php, symfony

Symfony2 keeps cache in app\cache folder

Is there a way to change it to different path?

Thanks for any help!

**Answer:**

Thanks to Aurelijus Valeiša for this!

I did add method (to AppKernel.php) like this:

```
public function getCacheDir()
{
    // Remove whole method if you want to go back to the original cache folder
    return 'c:/Users/Mike/Documents/www/cache/'.$this->environment;
}
```

If you want to do the same with logs folder add this method:

```
public function getLogDir()
{
    // Remove whole method if you want to go back to the original log folder
    return 'c:/Users/Mike/Documents/www/logs';
}
```

Make a note that both methods just overwrite original which are created in Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, in `app/AppKernel.php` file override `getCacheDir()` method (defined in `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel`).
As the example, in your extended `AppKernel` class you could have:

```
public function getCacheDir()
{
    return $this->rootDir.'/superduper_cache/'.$this->environment;
}
```